# How to programmatically generate a window.event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I am currently unit testing some javascript, where it handles an event raised by clicking on a certain item in the window.  Below is a snipet of the code:

```
function someFunction() 
{

    var evt = window.event ? window.event : event;

    if (evt == null) { return; }

    var nodeElement = evt.srcElement;

    if (nodeElement == null) { return; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My current approach is to try to create a custom event in my test file which will populate window.event so I can at least get to test the nodeElement == null part.  But I am having difficulties doing so (being not from a Javascript backgound).  How do I actually create a custom event (in IE)?  I'm currently doing unit testing using JsTestDriver so no html file is used.  I do not mind using jQuery or just plain Javascript solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you do `$('#some-id').click()` etc?

Comment: @Alex: I'm new to jQuery as well.  Do you mind explaning what is some-id please?

Comment: Ok I tried $(#this').click() and $(#this.document).click().  None worked...

Comment: Make sure that you enclose #this in quotes - spend a short time looking at the 'selectors' section of the jquery docs (http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Comment: "#some-id" is a css selector, where some-id would be an id attribute on a html tag

Comment: UPDATE: I tried $('window').click(); (and its variants, meaning w/w/o # or w/w/o ''), and so far I have not been able to get anything from window.event (always return null). I tried .bind and .trigger, but I'm guessing that my logic must be way off... no luck at all.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely use jQuery (or some other framework).  It will make your life easier. I am sure every browser will have a different way of triggering the event.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events

With jQuery you just do something like

```
$(window).trigger("eventname")
```

Comment: Not sure why this had been upvoted, but it's totally off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I currently wrote [a blog post series](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/10/20/event-driven-programming-with-jquery-part-1-what-is-event-driven/) about custom events in jQuery. You can use `.trigger` and `.bind` and it is really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

As alex has pointed out in his comment, you can use jQuery to create events with

```
$("css selector here").jQueryEventFunction(functionToCall);
```

So, following your example, if you want to invoke `someFunction` when a label is clicked you can do:

```
$("#label-id").click(someFunction);
```

Now, if you want to simulate clicking it

```
$("#label-id").click();
```

And that will do it.

**EDIT** For the window event you can use

```
$(window).click(someFunction);
```

That will bind any click done in the window to `someFunction`. And if you call `$(window).click();` a click event will be simulated, calling `someFunction`.

Comment: @MaKLaV_eS: what if I just want to create a window event? From what I know, in order to trigger an event, all I need to do is to click in the browser somewhere and it will trigger an event. I want to catch that event so I can at least be able to test the latter condition in my javascript.

Comment: @MaKLaV_eS: Thanks for the update.  I have tried your code, and also followed the examples from http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click, but its still not working.  Looks like the problem has something to do with JsTestDriver itself.